# ¿Cómo recupero un atributo de un objeto usando tkinter y python 3.4?

Tags: python

El main crea una ventana principal y llama al objeto `vent` del módulo(claseejem.py), el cual abre una ventana emergente (toplevel) y recibe una fecha en un objeto Entry, que a su vez debe asignar a un atributo del objeto vent.

Cuando intento recuperar el dato en main, me muestra el atributo vacío; parece que no actualiza el dato hasta que no se cierra el ciclo mainloop de la ventana principal.

Deseo recuperar el dato sin cerrar la ventana principal.

Agradezco su ayuda valiosa.

Código:

```
# Módulo mainejem.py

from tkinter import * 
from claseejem import *

# Crea la Ventana principal
ventana1 = Tk()
ventana1.geometry('200x100')

# Crea un objeto de la clase vent del módulo claseejem.py
vt = vent(ventana1)
# Se espera que este objeto nos proporcione el atributo fecha

# Intento recuperar la fecha
print('dato regresado',vt.fecha.get())  # fecha vacía

ventana1.mainloop()
print('dato regresado',vt.fecha.get())  # Aquí si se recupera el dato pero al cerrar la ventana principal 
# Pero no quiero que se cierre la ventana principal.
........................................................

# Módulo claseejem.py

from tkinter import * 

class vent:
    ''' El propósito de esta clase es Abrir una ventana emergente y solicite una fecha '''

    def __init__(self, ventana):
        tl = Toplevel(ventana, bg="Orange")
        tl.title("Modificar Datos")
        tl.geometry('600x400')
        tl.focus_set()
        tl.grab_set()
        tl.transient(master=ventana)

        self.fecha = StringVar()
        inf = StringVar(tl)        

        entry1 = Entry(tl, textvariable=inf)
        entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        label1 = Label(tl, text='Hija', bg="red")
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        Button(tl, text="copia", command= lambda a = inf : self.copia(a)).grid(row=0, column=2)

    # Esta función crea un atributo donde se asigna la fecha ingresada
    def copia(self, i):
        self.fecha = i
```

Answer (score 2):

Los `StringVar` y familia sirven para desacoplar los datos de su manipulación por el interface gráfico. Lo recomendable es crearlos fuera de la creación de las ventanas para tenerlos a buen recaudo.

Por otro lado, ¿cuándo se supone que se va a enterar la ventana principal que ha cambiado algo? ¿cuando se cierre la ventana que está por encima? ¿cuando se pulse el botón? Para resolver estos casos habría que estar escuchando eventos y actuar cuando haya cambios. Pero las *Variables* como `StringVar` están pensadas para simplificar las cosas. Se les puede asociar una función `callback` para monitorizar cualquier cambio que sufran, con lo que no hace falta indagar en los eventos de la ventana.

Te pongo cómo sería tu código con estos cambios:

#### módulo mainejem.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from claseejem import Ventana

class VentanaPrincipal(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        master.geometry('200x100')
        super().__init__(master)

        self.fecha = tk.StringVar()
        self.fecha.trace("w", self.cambio)

        self.info = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.fecha)
        self.info.pack()

        self.pack()

        self.vent = Ventana(self, self.fecha)

    def cambio(self, *args):
        print("Cambio:", self.fecha.get())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = tk.Tk()
    w = VentanaPrincipal(r)
    r.mainloop()

    print("Valor final:", w.fecha.get())

    import tkinter as tk
```

#### módulo classejem.py

```
class Ventana(tk.Toplevel):
    '''El propósito de esta clase es Abrir una ventana emergente y solicite una fecha'''

    def __init__(self, ventana, fecha):
        super().__init__(ventana, bg="Orange")
        self.title("Modificar Datos")
        self.geometry('600x400')
        self.focus_set()
        self.grab_set()
        self.transient(master=ventana)

        self.fecha = fecha

        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text='Hija', bg="red")
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.boton = tk.Button(self, text="copia", command=self.pulsa)
        self.boton.grid(row=0, column=2)

    def pulsa(self):
        self.fecha.set(self.entry1.get())
```

Comment: Excelente!!!!   ChemaCortes.  Esto es lo que necesitaba saber.  Mil gracias.

Comment: Me alegro. Si consideras que es una buena respuesta, [*"acéptala"*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) como buena para que conste.